# What is the replacement for the deprecated org.jboss.resteasy.spi exceptions?

Tags: java, resteasy, deprecated

Recently I updated from using RESTEasy 2.3.6.Final to the latest one and it turns out that the org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException and org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnauthorizedException are deprecated. Is there a replacement for these?

Answer (score 2):

NotFoundException has been pulled upstream: JAX-RS API itself now contains it: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.html

RESTeasy 3.0.4 Javadocs briefly mention this: "JAX-RS now has this exception" http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/NotFoundException.html

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [RESTEasy source code](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy), you could see that the [`UnauthorizedException`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/UnauthorizedException.java) class does not contain any documentation about the deprecation replacement, but it contains the following comment:

```
Thrown by RESTEasy when HTTP Unauthorized (401) is encountered
```

Running the following command in the source code root folder will let you find any similar documented class:

```bash
find . -name "*.java" -type f -exec grep "when HTTP Unauthorized (401)" {} \; -print
```

It returns:

```
./resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/UnauthorizedException.java
./security/resteasy-crypto/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/security/doseta/UnauthorizedSignatureException.java
```

Checking the header of the second file (`./security/resteasy-crypto/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/security/doseta/UnauthorizedSignatureException.java`), you can see:

```java
/**
 * Thrown by RESTEasy when HTTP Unauthorized (401) is encountered
 */
 public class UnauthorizedSignatureException extends ReaderException
 {
    ...
```

So, [`org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.UnauthorizedSignatureException`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/security/resteasy-crypto/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/security/doseta/UnauthorizedSignatureException.java) looks like the best candidate to replace [`org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnauthorizedException`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/UnauthorizedException.java) based in the similarity of their declarations.

Applying a similar approach for the [`NotFoundException`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/NotFoundException.java) didn't return any results, searching for files with similar names (containing `NotFound` as part of the file name):

```bash
 $ find . -name "NotFound*" -type f
```

returned:

```
./examples/oreilly-workbook-as7/ex07_1/src/main/java/com/restfully/shop/services/NotFoundExceptionMapper.java
./examples/oreilly-workbook-as7/ex07_1/src/main/java/com/restfully/shop/services/NotFoundException.java
./examples/oreilly-workbook/ex07_1/src/main/java/com/restfully/shop/services/NotFoundExceptionMapper.java
./examples/oreilly-workbook/ex07_1/src/main/java/com/restfully/shop/services/NotFoundException.java
./resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/NotFoundException.java
./jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.java
./resteasy-links/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/links/impl/NotFoundException.java
```

Inspecting the class at `./jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.java`:

```java
/**
 * A runtime exception indicating a resource requested by a client was
 * {@link javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status#NOT_FOUND not found} on the server.
 *
 * @author Sergey Beryozkin
 * @author Marek Potociar
 * @since 2.0
 */
public class NotFoundException extends ClientErrorException {
  ...
```

The header comment states that the class basically works as the deprecated class does, so  [`javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.java) looks like an alternative (maybe a replacement) for [`org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/NotFoundException.java) class. Hope this could be of help.

Comment: See javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException.

Answer (score 0):

This is a runtime exception indicating a resource requested by a client was not found on the server.
Add below entry into your web.xml.
This works with latest RESTEasy.

```html
<context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.org.abc.xyz.MainClassName</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You can specify fully qualified name of your JAX-RS resource class name you want to register.
If you have multiple classes entries, use comma delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of Deprecated Exception list and its replacement.
Link to documentation is https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/javadocs/deprecated-list.html#exception